# Hiding Getting Started Tiles

Tags: 2013, css, promoted-links, brand

We have our Farm globally branded and I would like to remove a specific tile from the default 'Getting Started' Promoted Links Web Part. I would like to remove the tile 'What's your Style' so the user can't change the look

At the moment, I'm using CSS to hide the element by ID, but this also hides any subsequent Promoted Tile Links with the same ID. That is no good.

```
#Tile_WPQ2_4_1
{
    display:none;
}
```

Any alternatives to this? Maybe select the Tile by Inner Text, or there must be a hidden list that drives 'Getting Started' where I can remove this tile.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use jQuery to look for inner html and hide if it contains `What's your Style`

```
jQuery('#Tile_WPQ2_4_1').each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).html().indexOf("What's your Style") > -1) {
       jQuery(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: pretty close. Definitely helped me. I'll post the exact answer since I can't find this anywhere on the web

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide one of the default tiles in 'Getting Started', here is the script to do so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id*=" + 'promotedlinksbody' + "] > div").each(function(){
        if($(this).html().indexOf("What's your style") > -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can this be done using powershell csom code for SharePoint online?

Comment: This should work for SP online. Put it in CEWP on the page or at the Master Page level